# Is declaring a gui component as private counted as encapsulation?

Tags: java, encapsulation

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
```

I then used getters for the text field

```
st.setString(1, textField.getText());
```

Can declaring a gui component (a text field) as private be called encapsulation?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is counted as encapsulation.  By declaring the `JTextField textField` field as `private` you are preventing direct access to it from outside the class.   Other classes are not aware of the `textField` field or that it is a `JTextField` object.  They can't depend on the field existing, etc; i.e. no coupling.  They can't directly read or write the field; i.e. encapsulation.

The code that contains the `textField.getText()` call must be part of this class.  Presumably this is part of the implementation of the classes public API.  At worst it is a *partial* relaxation of the encapsulation to allow the caller to see the text.  At best, it is just part of the API.

Encapsulation doesn't mean "no information comes out".  (That would be useless!)  What it means is that access is limited (by design) to what is necessary, and (when appropriate) mediated by the encapsulating methods.  This makes it easier to understand the code and how the parts interact, especially when the code-base is extensive.

Comment: Thank you so much that really helped. You saved my day.